# Inserting images into an RichTextArea in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, rich-text-editor

For my current project i need to offer the user the possibility to write text with images that he can insert into the text. With the built in RichTextArea of vaadin7 i can write the text but won't upload / insert images from the local drive of the user just specify the url of the image where it is available on the web. How can i hook into the "Insert Image" Function of the RTA? Or are there any other ways to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try the [Vaadin add-ons directory](https://vaadin.com/directory), and specifically for your use case I would try editors such as [CKeditor](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/ckeditor-wrapper-for-vaadin)

Answer (score 0):

What I did is create an Add Image button and then converted the uploaded image into a base64 image. Then I just directly inserted the image into the RichTextArea.